# eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped

Tags: ethernet, kernel

I have latest Raspberry Pi 3 running raspbian. I'm using it as WiFI AP with a bridge interface between wlan0 and eth0. I was working fine since few weeks ago when suddenly network stopped to work. I googoled the error but I haven not found anything useful

```
[   30.108102] brcmfmac: brcmf_add_if: ERROR: netdev:wlan0 already exists
[   30.108115] brcmfmac: brcmf_add_if: ignore IF event
[   30.281377] br0: port 2(wlan0) entered forwarding state
[   30.281440] br0: port 2(wlan0) entered forwarding state
[   30.864784] brcmfmac: brcmf_proto_bcdc_hdrpull: wlan0: non-BCDC packet received, flags 0x46
[   36.328375] brcmfmac: brcmf_proto_bcdc_hdrpull: wlan0: non-BCDC packet received, flags 0x7e
[   52.045199] brcmfmac: brcmf_proto_bcdc_hdrpull: wlan0: non-BCDC packet received, flags 0x7e
[   83.807211] brcmfmac: brcmf_proto_bcdc_hdrpull: wlan0: non-BCDC packet received, flags 0x7e
[  148.794872] brcmfmac: brcmf_proto_bcdc_hdrpull: wlan0: non-BCDC packet received, flags 0x7e
[  157.709856] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
[  157.709882] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
[  158.369837] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
[  158.369879] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
[  159.249852] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
[  159.249878] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
[  159.249912] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
[  170.838881] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
[  170.838950] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
[  170.838996] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
[  170.839017] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
[  170.839054] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
[  170.839082] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
[  170.839101] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
[  170.839121] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
[  170.839151] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
[  171.589843] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
[  185.037375] net_ratelimit: 3 callbacks suppressed
[  185.037406] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
[  185.037439] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
[  185.037456] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
[  185.037472] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
[  185.037487] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
[  185.037503] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
[  185.037518] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
[  185.041134] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
[  185.042593] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
[  185.709850] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
[  201.834625] net_ratelimit: 2 callbacks suppressed
[  201.834659] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
[  201.834719] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
[  201.834763] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
[  201.834784] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
[  201.834827] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
[  201.834884] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
[  201.834905] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
[  201.834945] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
[  201.834989] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
[  201.835014] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
[  212.115072] net_ratelimit: 6 callbacks suppressed
[  212.115094] brcmfmac: brcmf_proto_bcdc_hdrpull: wlan0: non-BCDC packet received, flags 0x7e
[  213.949862] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
[  213.949923] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
[  213.949965] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
[  275.626516] brcmfmac: brcmf_proto_bcdc_hdrpull: wlan0: non-BCDC packet received, flags 0x7e
[  276.131185] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
[  276.131225] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
[  276.131243] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
[  276.131259] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
[  276.131275] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
[  276.131290] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
[  281.122416] brcmfmac: brcmf_proto_bcdc_hdrpull: wlan0: non-BCDC packet received, flags 0x56
[  284.952419] brcmfmac: brcmf_proto_bcdc_hdrpull: wlan0: non-BCDC packet received, flags 0x56
[  293.629432] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
[  306.227779] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
[  306.227836] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
[  306.227871] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
[  306.227890] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
[  310.850382] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
[  322.828883] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
[  322.828929] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
[  322.828969] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
[  322.828986] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
[  322.829019] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
[  322.829035] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
[  322.829067] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
[  322.829083] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
[  322.829116] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
[  322.829132] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
```

Answer (score 2):

There appears to be a (long-standing) issue with the smsc95xx driver: https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/issues/673